# When I get down-vote, is there any way to ask down-voter that why my post got that?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes

Whenever someone asks a question that's his/her working problem that he/she is unable to fix that bug that's why asked it here. Maybe that person is just beginner and our experts give down-vote to he/her without knowing what was wrong.

So my question is why system doesn't ask down-voter what's is wrong in this? So the person asking question can correct it next time.

Comment: I understand your sentiment. When I leave a downvote I usually leave an explanation. If the Poster edits and fixes the issue, I'm willing to reverse and often even up-vote. But that's not everybody's approach. As much as I'd like it if OP's or answer givers could address **@downvoter** I also appreciate what a pain that would cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downvoting is anonymous.

Therefore there isn't a definite way to know why your post was downvoted. It's nice to leave an explanation when downvoting but since it's not required, people often don't do so.

I often see people comment on their own post, asking why they received the downvote, but as I said, this doesn't guarantee an explanation. This is often a lost effort given that the downvoter didn't bother to leave a comment to begin with.

I would argue that there are enough good people in the community, that you will often receive an upvote to outweigh the negativity. This is of course assuming that the post was unrightfully downvoted. You will often see this with revenge downvoting.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask for the reason in a comment on your post. The downvoter or some one else who knows the reason why the post was down voted will tell you.

If you post a comment and nobody is saying anything then forget the downvote and move on

Comment: when I am new here and having 1 up vote and 2 down vote reputation 5, how can I can get reputation to ask and answer any question?

Comment: @Ashok_Karale you can ask and answer a question with 1 reputation

Comment: Ideally you should have looked trough all the rules before posting so you can simply avoid having downvotes.